# Disable viewing/listing rights to users

Tags: centos, permissions

When I create a new user, s/he can browse the filesystem. E.g. `ll /`.

How can I restrict the user to a few select directories?

Comment: removing the _r_ bit of a directory , a user cannot list it , but still can create , read , and write files and sudirs inside .

Comment: basically we can deny all access to sensitive directories like /var/log , and limit listing of less sensitive but functionally essential dirs like /bin . the exact filesystem level pattern is still left to figure out .

Comment: This question is not specific enough.

Comment: Users need read permission to many system directories. E.g. if you remove read permission from `/`, they won't be able to use `pwd`.